Concerns About Syntax Errors and Code Logic in My Flutter Course
I'm working through a Flutter course and ran into some syntax errors. I suspect the course materials might be outdated, as I had to modify some code to get it working. I'm worried that these changes might have introduced unintended consequences, impacting the code's logic or flow. Could you please clarify if this is a concern?
The sample code :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({@required this.colour, this.cardChild, this.onPress});

  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The code I changed and fix :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChangeableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ChangeableCard(
      {required this.color,
      this.cardChild,
      required this.onPressButton,
      super.key});
  final Color color;
  final Widget? cardChild;
  final Function() onPressButton;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPressButton,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: color,
        ),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: cardChild,
      ),
    );
  }
}

In the code required instead of @required:
final Function() onPressButton; 

instead of
final Function onPress;


nothing special. It is ok. Just new syntax, no impact. Keep doing your job. Good luck.

@required is VERY old.  I hope you can find some more modern material elsewhere.

Use VoidCallback instead of Function at onTap in GestureDetector, everything will work well.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({@required this.colour, this.cardChild, this.onPress});

  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final VoidCallback onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

